# perl regular expression to give back parts of debian/ubuntu package names

Tags: regex, perl, ubuntu, debian

Is there any perl regex trick that will correctly recognize and give back

1. package name
2. package upstream
3. package maintainer version

and will work with ANY ubuntu/debian package? (NOTE: ANY)

Below is just an EXAMPLE.
For example, `sipcalc-1.2.3-1` would be parsed like:

```
$1 = sipcalc
$2 = 1.2.3
$3 = 1
```

`libapache2-mod_perl-2.3.4-ubuntu5` would be parsed like

```
$1 = libapache2-mod_perl
$2 = 2.3.4
$3 = ubuntu5
```

etc.

package names and version numbers are fictious, and are here just give an idea of what i need.
and, this could use split// as well.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them stored in separate arrays use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 
use Data::Dumper;

    my @names = ('sipcalc-1.2.3-1', 'libapache2-mod_perl-2.3.4-ubuntu5', 'libapt-inst1.4-0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10','isc-dhcp-common-4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.8', 'libaprutil1-1.3.12+dfsg-3');

my (@var1, @var2, @var3);
foreach (@names) {
    my ($match1, $match2, $match3) = ($_ =~ /(.*)\-([\d\.]+)\W([a-z]*.*)/i);
        push @var1, $match1;
        push @var2, $match2;
        push @var3, $match3;
    }

print Dumper (\@var1);
print Dumper (\@var2);
print Dumper (\@var3);
```

Output:

```
 $VAR1 = [
          'sipcalc',
          'libapache2-mod_perl',
          'libapt-inst1.4',
          'isc-dhcp-common',
          'libaprutil1'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          '1.2.3',
          '2.3.4',
          '0.8.16',
          '4.1',
          '1.3.12'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          'ubuntu5',
          'exp12ubuntu10.10',
          'ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.8',
          'dfsg-3'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing dpkg -l on my system, I found that there are a lot of unique-looking cases.

Any successful regex will have to account for cases including the following:

> libapt-inst1.4-0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.10
>
> libaprutil1-1.3.12+dfsg-3
>
> isc-dhcp-common-4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.8

and doubtless some other weird ones.

Is there some sort of guide to the naming of these packages? Without some sort of framework to follow, given the sheer number of packages, **I don't think it's possible to answer this question.**

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my @packages=`rpm -qa`;
foreach my $package ( @packages )
 {
   print "Package $package \n";
   my @parts = split(/\-/, $package);
   my $last=$#parts;
   my $maint_ver=$parts[$last];
   my $ver=$parts[$last-1];
   pop @parts; pop @parts;
   my $package_name=join("-",@parts);
   if ($ver !~ /\d+.\d+/ )
      {
       print "package naming error: $package \n";
      }
   print "$package_name <-> $ver <->  $maint_ver \n";
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

"this could use split// as well." Seems like you have a answer...

Edit: quick regex. I'm not sure what all the possible formations for packages are.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $string1 = "libapache2-mod_perl-2.3.4-ubuntu5";

my @matches = $string1 =~ m/([a-z0-9\-_]+)-([0-9.]+)-([a-z0-9]+)/i;

print Dumper \@matches;


$VAR1 = [
      'libapache2-mod_perl',
      '2.3.4',
      'ubuntu5'
    ];
```

Comment: no, because i need "split with longest match possible", with regular split/-_/ I will have in the last case: `$1 = libapache2 $2 = mod $3 = perl $4 = ubuntu5`

Comment: Updated, with a regex example.